# How to send a message from a main module to notification module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

The code below is just a sample as the actual code I am having issues with is not something I can share, I am new to angular so the solution is not super apparent, something like this I could do using jQuery in a few seconds.

In my application I have a main module that runs ajax, when the ajax returns success or failure it needs to send a message to the notification module. In the sample code you can change all the modules to use one module and it works fine, the second I try to make it work as two modules it no longer works but no JS errors are thrown.

Treat the ID's

> theProcess

and

> theMessage

as the two separate modules, pretend *theProcess* is an ajax call that is made to the server and gets back a string response, then emit that string response to *theMessage* module.

See code below.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="theProcess" ng-controller="ControllerZero">
    <input ng-model="message">
    <button ng-click="handleClick(message);">LOG</button>
</div>
<div id="theMessage">
    <div ng-controller="ControllerOne">
            <input ng-model="message" >
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ControllerTwo">
            <input ng-model="message" >
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var masterModule = angular.module('masterModule', []);

masterModule.controller('ControllerZero', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.handleClick = function(msg) {
    $scope.$emit('handleEmit', {
      message: msg
    });
  };
}]);

var notificationModule = angular.module('notificationModule', ['masterModule']);

notificationModule.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('handleEmit', function(event, args) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast', args);
  });
});

notificationModule.controller('ControllerOne', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function(event, args) {
    $scope.message = 'ONE: ' + args.message;
  });
}]);

notificationModule.controller('ControllerTwo', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function(event, args) {
    $scope.message = 'TWO: ' + args.message;
  });
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('theProcess'), ['masterModule']);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('theMessage'), ['notificationModule']);
```

**[2 Module FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/qf9thv25/)**

[working example using one module](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/zkrp4t35/1/)

Comment: You bootstrap the 2 modules seperately, so you actually have 2 different applications on the page. try to bootstrap the lower most module (which no one is depend on), in this case "notificationModule'

Comment: @KobiCohen While your comment was difficult to follow without an example it did put me onto something and I was able to fix the issue, I'll post the answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kobi Cohen put me in the right direction and I was able to fix it, I wrapped the `div`'s in a parent `div` tag and then gave the tag an id called `container`, I then changed my bootstraps at the bottom of the page to read as:

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('container'), ['masterModule', 'notificationModule']);
```

[See updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/qf9thv25/1/)

Answer (score 0):

> You bootstrap the 2 modules seperately, so you actually have 2
>   different applications on the page. try to bootstrap the lower most
>   module (which no one is depend on), in this case "notificationModule'

– Kobi Cohen

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module